# brew doctor yields python config warning: should I remove these config files? (Mac)

Tags: python, macos, installation, homebrew

Mac seems to have Python installed already. brew doctor yields this:

```
brew doctor
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python-config
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2-config
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
```

Should I remove these config files, or would that cause issues? For me:

```
> which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

Also:

```
$ ls /usr/bin/pyth*
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  62752 Aug  6  2011 /usr/bin/python*
-rwxr-xr-x  6 root  wheel    925 Aug  6  2011 /usr/bin/python-config*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 Aug  6  2011 /usr/bin/python2.5@ -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82 Aug  6  2011 /usr/bin/python2.5-config@ -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 Aug  6  2011 /usr/bin/python2.6@ -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82 Aug  6  2011 /usr/bin/python2.6-config@ -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 Aug  6  2011 /usr/bin/python2.7@ -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82 Aug  6  2011 /usr/bin/python2.7-config@ -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  62752 Aug  6  2011 /usr/bin/pythonw*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76 Aug  6  2011 /usr/bin/pythonw2.5@ -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/pythonw2.5
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76 Aug  6  2011 /usr/bin/pythonw2.6@ -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pythonw2.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76 Aug  6  2011 /usr/bin/pythonw2.7@ -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew mainly uses built-in tools, so formulae generally should be built against system Python anyway. You shouldn't have any problem with them unless you override system Python with Homebrew ones (which is generally not recommended unless you need to do something special).

Comment: "which is generally not recommended unless you need to do something special" -> There’s nothing wrong with installing Homebrew’s Python; it’s more up-to-date than the system’s.

Comment: @bfontaine Things changed a bit since 2013. The line was accurate at the time, but Homebrew has changed their policies a bit, and now offers a lot of formulae that duplicates system libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It hasn't been an issue for me (most of my configs are in my home, rather than in homebrew). I think it's fine. As long as they're in your path, python will be able to find them; the only issue would be from a package or program you want to install with brew that needs to modify those config files. It could happen, but probably shouldn't with well-developed programs.